# Generate list of pointer to numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, pointers, cython

I am implementing in Cython (0.29) and use numpy (1.15.1)

```
cdef double *proj_points[1024]
cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="c"] array_ptr

for i in range(2):
    array_ptr = np.ascontiguousarray(self.projection[i] @ points, dtype=np.float)
    proj_points[i] = &array_ptr[0, 0]
```

In line 1, I define the array of pointers (on stack). In line 2 I define the `array_ptr` which I use to convert the numpy array into a C-style pointer to the numpy array.

#### Problem:

When I check the pointers in `proj_points`, they all indicate to the same memory element of the last numpy array (i.e. the second in the loop).

#### Current (unsatisfying) workaround

If I do the same hard-coded:

```
cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="c"] array_ptr0 = np.ascontiguousarray(self.projection[0] @ points, dtype=np.float)
self.proj_points[0] = &array_ptr0[0, 0]

cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="c"] array_ptr1 = np.ascontiguousarray(self.projection[1] @ points, dtype=np.float)
self.proj_points[1] = &array_ptr1[0, 0]
```

The pointers all point to the first value of the corresponding numpy array. This is what I also wish to have for the loop case above as there can be a variable number of pointers during runtime. How can I accomblish this?

#### What I also tried so far:

- `cdef` the `array_ptr` inside the loop, but this is illegal in Cython (`cdef` is only allowed in first level).
- put the part inside the loop into a function and have the `cdef` inside function but this did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers to arrays are not part of the Python reference counting scheme so they don't stop the array from being destroyed.

Therefore, once `array_ptr` is reassigned at the start of each loop Python destroys the array it used to hold. This means that the previous element of `proj_points` is now a pointer to an array that no longer exists, and what you get if you try to read it is completely undefined.

You need to retain a Python reference to any numpy array that you hold a pointer to.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is indeed a missing piece in my understanding Cython code (I am in my first week of trying out). I put all the numpy arrays in a Python-list then filled that list with the numpy arrays that I want to point to and finally collect the pointers in another loop. (probably would also work in one loop but that is clearer).